# How to start and stop an animation of a rotating ImageView with button

Tags: java, android, animation, rotation

I want to press play button and then spin a disc: `imageRound`. At pause I want to stop the disc at current position, and then on play continue from current position.

I am trying to get each time the angle with `imageRound.getRotation()` but it goes back to 0 each time. My code is as follows:

```
playButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            if (playShow) {
                                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_pressed);
                            } else {
                                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_pressed);}
                            return true; //handle the touch event
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            if (playShow) {
                                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_default);
                                RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(imageRound.getRotation(), 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                        0.5f,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                                rotate.setDuration(5000);
                                imageRound.startAnimation(rotate);
                                playShow=false;
                            } else {
                                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_default);
                                imageRound.setRotation(imageRound.getRotation()); //(Not working) Set angle and stop animation
                                imageRound.clearAnimation();
                                playShow=true;
                            }
                            return true; // handle the touch event
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of SanthoshKumar this is the fully working code which does the trick in my case:

```
playButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (playShow) {
                            playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_pressed);
                        } else {
                            playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_pressed);
                        }
                        return true; //handle the touch event
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (playShow) {
                            playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_default);
                            anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageRound, "rotation", imageRound.getRotation(), 360f);
                            anim.setDuration(20000);
                            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                            anim.start();//
                            playShow = false;
                            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                            }

                        } else {
                            playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_default);
                            anim.cancel();                             
                            playShow = true;
                            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                mediaPlayer.pause();
                            }

                        }
                        return true; // handle the touch event
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `imageRound.getRotation()` return 0 each time? RotateAnimation doesn't change the property of the view. Use `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageview ,"rotation", 0f, 360f)` This changes the rotation property of the view directly.